# Does java give a garbage data to a variable before you assign it?

Tags: java

In some other programming languages like C++ if you declared a variable x and then tried to print it before giving it an initial value, it will get a garbage data (like: -59382886742)

```
int x;
print(x);
```

In Java, does the compiler give a random value to the variable before you assign it or it just reserve a location on the memory for it without a value?
because when you try to print a variable before assigning it it will give you an error here

Comment: in java you cannot use variable that is uninitialized, so maybe there is garbage data but compiler disallows you from accessing it anyway

Comment: Short answer: no.  Fields (heap data) are initialized to zero.  And local variables like you show must be initialized by the programmer manually; with no initialization like you show it's a syntax error.